# Justify why a maximal-planar graph cannot have vertices of degree ≤ 2.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Justify why a maximal-planar graph cannot have vertices of degree ≤ 2.

Some definitions:
A planar graph is a graph that can be embedded in the plane, it can be drawn on the plane in such a way that its edges intersect only at their endpoints. In other words, it can be drawn in such a way that no edges cross each other.

A planar graph is called maximal planar if adding an
edge between any two non-adjacent vertices results in a non-planar
graph.

Another exam question that I came across while learning for my upcoming discrete math exam. Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bear in mind this is false for a triangle, which seems to fit the definition of maximal planar graph.  So you’ll need to use the fact that your graph has more than three vertices.  What do you know about planar graphs?  What techniques are available to you to prove that a graph is or isn’t planar?

Comment: A similar problem has been discussed in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543085/prove-that-a-maximal-planar-graph-triangulation-of-v3-has-minimum-degree-3